# Using independent samples t-test for paired data?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

we have a 'problem' when analysing data. It's a psychological experiment where participants could choose the upcoming condition, let's call them A, B, C, D. We are interested in analysing whether we find predictors about which condition they choose depending on the error rates in the previous block.

Just as an example, suppose they did condition A and struggled, then they tend to choose B next. Suppose they did A but were fine, then they tend to choose C next. So we have data like:

Transition A=>B  - Average error rates in A: 30%, based on N = 50

Transition A=>C - Average error rates in A: 10%, based on N = 35

Because participants can choose the condition, we don't have the same number of transitions for each participant, and some participants never did some transitions. Thus, we have a decent sample size for the above (usually N between 20 and 50).

However, now the challenge: We would like to compare in the above example whether the 30% is significantly higher than the 10%. For that we used a paired-sample t-test. However, for such a test we can only use those participants who have data for transitions A=>B and A=>C which greatly reduces the available N, in some tests down to 10. Another problem is that these tests would test only a sub-section of participants, so they actually don't compare 30% (N=50) vs 10% (N=35), but instead the new mean error rates from the 10 participants who have data for both transitions, so it may actually be 21% (N=10) vs 15% (N=10). [all hypothetical data to illustrate the point]

Thus, our idea was to maybe treat the data as between-subject data, ignoring the fact that (in this example) 10 participants actually contribute to both conditions. On the one hand, we should loose statistical power because we can't account for between-subject variance anymore, but on the other hand we may gain quite a bit of power because of the increased sample sizes (and the tests would actually relate to the overall data of 30% and 10%).

However, does the dependency between groups create a problem? Note, that while a portion of participants are members of both groups, different data of the participants are used when assigned to the different groups (i.e., it's not the same data of the participant used in group 1 (A=>B) and group 2 (A=>C).

Best wishes,
Andre